# AG Grid Column Filter List Missing Checkbox Icons

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We're in the process of using AG Grid in an application to display and edit data, but are having some trouble with the column filter lists.

The icons for the columns being filtered do not have checkmark icons. The outline around the checkmark boxes changes colors, but there are no icons. I was able to recreate the issue in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-galois-xx6b3z. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Expected behavior:

- Checkbox icons should be visible as shown in AG Grid examples: https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/filter-set-filter-list/sorting-set-filter-values/packages/vanilla/index.html

Notes:

- I created a very basic grid (see https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-galois-xx6b3z) to ensure that this issue is not related to any of the customizations we have added to our project
- I tried using custom icons (see this in AG Grid's documentation), which were also not visible: https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/filter-set-filter-list/sorting-set-filter-values/packages/vanilla/index.html

Comment: You are using Alpine theme without fonts. That is the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use Alpine theme with different fonts.
For this you will need to define CSS variable that will point to a different font:

```
.ag-theme-alpine, .ag-theme-alpine-dark {
  --ag-icon-font-family: agGridMaterial;
}
```